# How to print attributes of a json file

Tags: python, json, http

I would appreciate some help: how could I print just the country from the info obtained via this API call? Thanks!

```
import requests
import json

 
url = "https://randomuser.me/api/"
data = requests.get(url).json()

print(data)
```

Comment: `data` isn't JSON any more; it's just a `dict` that was *initialized* from a JSON object. (You don't even need the `import json`, as you aren't using the `json` module directly; the `Response` object returned by `requests.get` is.)

Answer (score 2):

You should play a little more with the json in order to learn how to use it, a helpful way to understand them is to go layer by layer printing the keys `dict.keys()` to see where you should go next if you dont have a documentation

in this particular case it returns a dictionary with the following first layer structure:

```
{
"results": [ ... ]
"info": { ... }
}
```

where results contains a single dictionary inside, therefore we can take

`data['results'][0]` to wok with

there is 'location', and there is a 'country', you can access this in that order to print the country:

```
print(data['results'][0]['location']['country'])
```